# why keras model does not improve

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, model

so this is my code in keras in order to do multi-classe classification, however it gives always the same results (acc =0.3212 val_acc=0.3227), I tried to change only the code of model with a pretrained vgg and I got good results. I tried also to code it in pytorch and the model imroved also. so I'm struggling with this model I dont know why it's not working.
PS: the other parts(datagenerator, ...) are all good because I tried them on vgg and it worked.
Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid


path = '/content/train/'
for folder in os.listdir(path):
print(len(os.listdir(path + folder))) 


from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
def createModel():
  model = keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(224, 224, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())


  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    
    
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    
    
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    
    
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    
  model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, activation ='softmax'))

  return model


#Augmentation des données 
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=5,  # rotation de +5 deg
    validation_split=0.1)  #10% de la base de données c'est données de validation

#Train & Validation Split
train_dataset = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32,
                                             directory='/content/train',
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             target_size=(224, 224),
                                             subset="training",
                                             class_mode='categorical')

validation_dataset = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32,
                                             directory='/content/train',
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             target_size=(224, 224),
                                             subset="validation",
                                             class_mode='categorical')

#Organize data for our predictions
test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_dataset = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(
                                             directory='/content/test',
                                             shuffle=False,
                                             target_size=(224, 224),
                                             class_mode=None)


#avec categorical cross entropy on va tester adam et RMSprop
model_adam = createModel()
model_RMSprop = createModel()

model_adam.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model_RMSprop.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
history_adam = model_adam.fit(train_dataset, epochs=60, validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

Comment: Have you tried with a model that's not as complex?

Comment: @Djinn I have tried to delete many layers from it and it still gives allways the same acc/loss that's very confusing

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing the `class_mode='spasse'` and `loss = SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` because your labels are not one_hot encoded. Also, try by decreasing the model size with less layers and add the [dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#add_dropout) layer which will randomly dropping out a number of output features of the layer during training.

Check this out:

```
model_adam.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['acc'])
history_adam = model_adam.fit(train_dataset, epochs=20, validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 15/20
104/104 [==============================] - 50s 477ms/step - loss: 0.2948 - acc: 0.8929 - val_loss: 1.2504 - val_acc: 0.6511
Epoch 16/20
104/104 [==============================] - 50s 477ms/step - loss: 0.2751 - acc: 0.8932 - val_loss: 1.4784 - val_acc: 0.6593
Epoch 17/20
104/104 [==============================] - 49s 474ms/step - loss: 0.2518 - acc: 0.9080 - val_loss: 1.4702 - val_acc: 0.6731
Epoch 18/20
104/104 [==============================] - 50s 483ms/step - loss: 0.2213 - acc: 0.9159 - val_loss: 1.6294 - val_acc: 0.6209
Epoch 19/20
104/104 [==============================] - 50s 476ms/step - loss: 0.2136 - acc: 0.9226 - val_loss: 1.6590 - val_acc: 0.6511
Epoch 20/20
104/104 [==============================] - 50s 477ms/step - loss: 0.2195 - acc: 0.9192 - val_loss: 1.9785 - val_acc: 0.6511
```

Please find the replicated code [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/bdeae7ad0f2ba48471b8be8334af101d/74257000.ipynb#scrollTo=ulpOw3PQbtpi) here for your reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that my model was suffering from vanishing gradient descent, as a solution I added Batch Normalization layers